# loadHTMLString from MainBundle or Documents Directory. Possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When showing a html file in a UIWebView, is it possible to first try to load the images from the DocumentsDirectory, and if it doesn't exist, load from the main bundle?

The reason is I dynamically load the html file from the server and store it locally, and want to do the same with the images. Often times, Images are added and the img tag code below will only load the image from the bundle, and not the documents directory where the downloaded images live.

Thanks in advance

```
<img src="myImage.jpg"/>

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Comment: Ask the question very clearly

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is this code

```
-(void) loadWebView
{
    NSString *termsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terms_conditions" ofType:@"html"];
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:termsFilePath
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:&err];

    [webView loadData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="file:///Users/MyMac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A6780B96-2F9C-418A-BE5C-5A8136A1B9C4/data/Containers/Data/Application/11245AB0-8736-4931-980C-951604F1CB8B/tmp/myImage.jpg">
```

As you can see, you need set the image path to src attribute of `<image>` tag. The path should be file://, I was try without file:// and image didn't show. Hope this helps.